# Exported function is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, babeljs, commonjs

I'm facing an issue with my Mocha tests in Typescript, I fear it is related to Babel, but I am really not sure what's happening.

Essentially, I have a function that is being exported in a file

```
// src/my-ts-lib/tests/components/factoryMocks/componentConfigMocks.ts

...

export function getRandomConfig(type?: string): ComponentConfig {
  const randomComponentType = type || randomType();
  return {
    type: randomComponentType,
    config: configLibrary[randomComponentType]
  }
}
```

And being imported in another, which is being called by a test:

```
// src/my-ts-lib/tests/components/RouteComponent/mocks/routeMocks.ts

...

import { getRandomConfig } from '../../factoryMocks/componentConfigMocks';

..

export const getSingleRouteConfigMock = (componentType?: string): RouteProps => {
  const defaultComponentType = 'PageLayout';
  return {
    childComponent: {
      type: componentType || defaultComponentType,
      config: getRandomConfig(componentType || defaultComponentType)
    },
    pageName: randomString(),
    path: randomString(),
  };
};

...
```

When running the tests, I get the following error:

```
RouteCompnent/mocks/routeMocks.ts:10
      config: getRandomConfig(componentType || defaultComponentType),
                                           ^
TypeError: componentConfigMocks_1.getRandomConfig is not a function
    at Object.exports.getSingleRouteConfigMock (/Users/.../routeMocks.ts:10:44)
```

If I comment the call and `console.log(getRandomConfig)` I can see that it is `undefined`. I do not know why this is happening. What's even weirder is that, in subsequent tests that call `getSingleRouteConfigMock`, this same `console.log` correctly outputs the function, meaning that it has been exported then.

I've fiddled around with Babel, Mocha, and Typescript configs but have had no success.

Here's the Babel config:

```
.babelrc

{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

The Mocha config:

```
mocha.opts

--require ts-node/register
--watch-extensions ts tsx
--require source-map-support/register
--recursive
--require @babel/register
--require @babel/polyfill
src/**/*.spec.**
```

And the Typescript config:

```
tsconfig.json

{
   "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir": "./dist/",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "module": "commonjs",
     "target": "es6",
     "jsx": "react"
   },
   "include": [
     "./src/**/*"
   ],
   "exclude": [
     "./src/**/*.spec.ts",
     "./src/my-ts-lib/components/**/*.spec.tsx",
     "./src/my-ts-lib/test-helpers/*"
   ],
 }
```

And the relevant sections of the `package.json`

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@babel/polyfill": "7.2.x",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.2.x",
  "@babel/preset-env": "7.2.x",
  "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.x",
  "@babel/register": "7.0.x",
  "babel-loader": "8.x",
  "mocha": "3.2.x",
  ...
}
```

Comment: `import { getRandomConfig }` aren't you exporting a single function not an object?

Comment: There are other functions being exported in the same file (`componentConfigMocks.ts`). If I'm not mistaken, this - `import { foo } from ...` - is the way to import an export that is not `default`, whether it is an object or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out I have a circular dependency. That's why this was not working.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the circular dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause for this symptom is that the function is actually missing in the module when you use a bundler like Parcel in production mode and it removes unused items (that particular issue discussed at [Empty Javascript File When Building With Parcel JS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268616/empty-javascript-file-when-building-with-parcel-js-2/70489709#70489709) ). Check the compiled module file and make sure that the name exists.