# Empty Javascript File When Building With Parcel JS 2

Tags: javascript, parceljs

In my package.json:

```
"dev": "parcel parcel/index.scss parcel/index.js --dist-dir assets --no-source-maps",
"build": "parcel build parcel/index.scss parcel/index.js --dist-dir assets --no-source-maps"
```

`dev` works. I get the expected results, which is my two index files are dropped into the root of my assets folder and both are populated with code. I can see my Sass and JS coming in from the separate files.

`build` will also output both index files, however, the js file is empty. The css file is populated.

No errors. Build completes.

All other settings are default.

I'm on a Win10 laptop running the latest node and npm.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like it might be a bug - could you link to a complete repo? One thing that's unusual about your setup is that you're building the `scss` and `js` files directly as CLI targets, instead of having the CLI command reference an `html` file that contains `script` and `link` tags that reference your `js` and `css` - see [this example from the docs](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/#project-setup). Do you get the same results if you structure your project that way?

Comment: Hi Andrew, it's structured that way because I'm a Shopify developer and there is a templating language involved called Liquid. All the files have a .liquid extension so I don't think I can point the CLI at the main entry file, which is 'theme.liquid'. I can try it out though. I was assuming it wouldn't work. I don't have a repo for it right now but I can put that together later today when I have some free time. Thanks for replying. Oh yeah, and I opened an issue for it a few days ago but not response yet: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7412

Comment: Makes sense with the liquid templates - I don't think that's supported by parcel at the moment - but it certainly could be with a plugin. When you have the repro ready, let me know and I'll take a look (it might also be a good idea to add it to the bug).

Comment: Andrew, here is a repo: https://github.com/preston-mro/preston-mro-dev-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what's happening:

Your `parcel/index.js` file has lines like this:

```js
import './scripts/global/global';
...
```

And the `./scripts/global/global` file has items that look like this:

```
function globalTest1() {
  console.log('testing from global.js function 1');
}
...
```

It looks like you are trying to build a bundle that exposes a bunch of functions in the global namespace.

That's not happening here because, by default, parcel is going to try to build a modern ESModule-based bundle (e.g. something that could be imported into an `<html>` file with `<script type="module>"`). Variables declared in these kinds of scripts are, by default, *not* part of the global namespace (see [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts)). Furthermore, in production mode (e.g. when you run `parcel build`) parcel tries to be smart to remove things that it can tell are not used within the bundle (see [parcel scope-hosting docs](https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/)). Since you aren't using *any* of the imports, they all get removed.

Parcel v1 used to support this scenario with a `--global` flag that hasn't been carried over to v2. There is a [near-term roadmap item](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/7345#user-content-umd) to support this scenario through a "UMD output format" - it's not fully implemented yet, but when it is, you should be able to define some global variable that will contain all the top-level exports from your bundle (see [PR #7240](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7240), [PR #7381](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7381), and [Issue #7312](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7312)).

In the meantime, you should be able to solve this scenario by explicitly assigning the things you want to be the global namespace to the `globalThis` variable in the entry script. Parcel will see that these items are used -- and therefore won't tree-shake them. Unfortunately, the process would involve a bit of manual boilerplate, but you should unblock you for now. For example, you could change your `parcel/index.js` file to expose all the exports from the `global.js` file in a global variable called `myGlobalFunctions`:

```js
import * as myGlobalFunctions from './scripts/global/global';
globalThis.myGlobalFunctions = myGlobalFunctions;
.....
```

(It would be up to you to choose a name and structure for these export(s), based on your scenario).

Comment: You nailed it when you said production mode is removing things that aren't being used. I tried your idea using globalThis and it worked. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Although your issue seems to be solved, I had a similar issue with building a JS library with Parcel 2 (empty compiled module), I’m just noting it here.

This entry in `package.json` fixed it: `"main": "dist/index.js"` (specify the path to the compiled module)

My module contains `export` statements.

One nuisance arising from this is that when you run parcel with a different target, you need to change or delete this entry. You can also let parcel ignore it ([following the docs](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#library-targets)) by adding `"targets": {"main": false}`, but then the above-mentioned hack for the `index.js` target doesn’t work either.

Comment: This comment put me on the right track after hours of futile searching. When there isn't a target specified, Parcel looks at `main` in package.json and builds it properly as a library. 

When you specify and build a target however, this behavior is different, and you get a bundle that is missing most of the necessary code for some reason.

The solution here is to add `"isLibrary": true` within every target entry in package.json